# Space Indentation Expected in ng lint

Tags: tslint

I keep getting error **"space indentation expected"** while running **ng lint**. It is a quite amount of lines that having the same issue in my application. 
How can I solve this warning?  Is anyone having face the similar issue ?

Comment: This is not the most efficient way of doing it but above the line that's throwing the error, put the following line: `// tslint:disable-next-line:indent`. If you can find a way to decorate it at the top of the function then that will be a bit better. Afterwards run `ng lint --type-check` and see if your files pass linting. If this helped you in anyway please mark it as a solution as opposed to a comment.

Comment: Actually, there is an opened bug in the library.
Please check out https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2814.

Answer (score 28):

By default ng lint expects indentation to be 2 spaces. You can change these settings in your tslint.json.

If you want to use 4 spaces:

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "spaces",
    4
]
```

If you want to use tabs (4 spaces wide):

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "tabs",
    4
]
```

See [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/) section of the docs for reference.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone came here because they're seeing this in vscode despite having a perfectly good tab at the start of the line do this:
Hit F1, type 'tabs' and select 'Convert indentation to tabs' and that should resolve it.

Comment: for me it was the other way around, type space and 'Convert Indentation to Spaces'.

Comment: That gets rid of the red underline, but when I save the file all the red lines come back again. I have been through the settings 5 times. What is adding back tabs on save?!