# Disable "space indentation expected" errors

Tags: angular-cli

Running ng lint gives me a lot of "space indentation expected" errors, reason being me using tabs instead of spaces. I'd be ok using 4 spaces instead of the tabs, but I can't work with 2-space-indentations.

I understand that the angular cli team currently [doesn't have any plans to change the 2 space indentations](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1252#issuecomment-281070150), but is there any way of configuring the linter that it doesn't raise warnings about it?

Excluding all .ts files from linting is not a feasable option for me, putting "tslint:disable-next-line:indent" in all of the files like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605561/space-indentation-expected-in-ng-lint?rq=1) is also quite annoying.

Comment: Try putting the override in your angular-cli.json

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Don't you have tslint.json in your project. You can try writing the rule there first. `"disable-next-line": "indent"`

Comment: "disable-next-line": "indent" didn't work, you led me on the right path though, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"indent": [
  true,
  "tabs",
  4
],
```

in the tslint.json did the trick. See [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/) reference in the docs.